# Triangle lengths without trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry

I was wondering that if you’re given all the angles of a right triangle and one side, can you find the other two sides WITHOUT trig?

I tried random stuff like equating pythagorean theorem to heron’s formula but it got very ugly very soon, and I doubt it works. Does anybody know of a way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Trig is defined as the ways to resolve such questions, so no.

Comment: If the hypoteneuse is one unit in length, then the other two sides are the sine and cosine of the two non-right angles. Thus finding the two sides **is** trigonometry.

Comment: How are you going to connect angles to lengths or areas and vice-versa without trigonometric functions?

Comment: In general no, but it may be possible if the angles are simple. For example, this is possible for 45 degrees, 30 degrees, 18 degrees and 15 degrees, the last two being more complicated than the first two. On the other hand, there's no simple formula for 20 degrees.